# Sharepoint 2013 & javascript post filtering/reordering list

Tags: javascript, user-interface, sharepoint

I'm no coding expert but have been asked to create an intranet page in SP2013 because I could do some basic HTML/CSS for my boss. The page is to have a table of services, whom the services are provided to and then against each location a tick if that location provides that service/recipient combo. As an intranet site I have limited authority to make edits—only via the web interface of SharePoint.

I can do a static HTML table no problem, but as there are circa 45 items and some may be more interested in the recipients or the services, my boss wants them to be able to sort/filter the table. As such, and thanks to Google, I have created a list and added some basic/crude CSS & Javascript as a Code Snippet webpart to the page to includes (a) hiding the Select and New Column columns (b) applying style classes to the relevant elements (c) replacing the yes/nos with ticks images or blanks

Now, when the page loads it all works great but whenever a reorder or filter is applied to the list view the `<tbody>` section of the table loses the impact of the javascript/styling. (table header remains fine)

Currently, I am using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push` to call the function that applies the formatting but don't know/cannot find how to ensure that script is reapplied once a filter/reorder is done.